# Lower case SOQL with 'IN' operator

Tags: soql, string

I am trying to make a `SOQL` query trying to match email ids with lower case:

```
SELECT Id, Custom_Email_Id from Custom_Object where Custom_Email_Id IN :list_of_email_ids
```

Here, I am trying to get all objects with its lower cased `Custom_Email_Id` in `list_of_email_ids`. I have tried searching in documentation but couldn't find an `SOQL` function to lower case string.

If this is not possible, is there any other way this could be done?

Comment: I'm curious as to the use case of this; case-insensitive id searching could return "duplicates" unless you're using the full 18-character id.

Comment: Note that case sensitivity only matters if the field itself is case sensitive. For example, `SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name IN ('test','foo','bar')` returns accounts with names: TeSt, Foo, BaR, bAr...

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for the info. I am matching on field type `Email` so I am guessing something like `SELECT Id, Email FROM Account WHERE Email IN ('TesT@asd.com','Foo@asd.com')` would return Id, Email for `test@asd.com` and `foo@asd.com`?

Comment: @sPaz Yes, email fields are not case sensitive by default, and use normal case folding (meaning upper- and lower-case letters are equal).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this through straight SOQL. You'd likely need to adjust case in Apex before running the SOQL query.

Something like

```
Set<String> list_of_email_ids_lc = new Set<String>();
for(String emailId : list_of_email_ids){
  list_of_email_ids_lc.add(emailId.toLowerCase());
}
List<Custom_Object> objects = [SELECT Id, Custom_Email_Id from Custom_Object where Custom_Email_Id IN :list_of_email_ids_lc];
```